# Getting Ajax Error [Object : Object]

Tags: java, ajax

I have to access my WebService to search data, but it gives me [an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWthp.png) :

> error[object:object]

I have run my webservice and it workedI don't know why I can't access it through ajax.

[This is my webservice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN9gW.png).

Comment: Please put more effort in your question by adding and formatting your code. No one would like to reproduce/test your case from a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

alert() prints the string representation of the arguments - hence if you pass an object, you'll get [object Object].

To inspect data, use console.log(data) better.